# How does Ember.js nest routes?

Tags: routes, ember.js

Sorry I'm new to ember.js. I really want to do is create a ember.js based app only for admin section. this app should be handle admin section urls only `http://mydomain.com/admin/` ( eg: /admin/photos/, /admin/users) others should be work as normal url's. Can I do this with ember.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Ember resources to nest routes. So for your example you want to do something like this:

```
AppName.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('admin', function() {
    this.route('photos');
    this.route('users');
  });
});
```

The above will create a `/admin/photos` and `/admin/users` route. mokane linked to the the right spot in the Ember docs, but for future-proofing, I'd like to just put the answer in the post so anyone else can see the answer even if the docs location ever changes.

NOTE: I'd like to include an important point made by Ugis Ozols in the comments below which is that in Ember, resources are usually nouns while routes are typically verbs. So you would usually have a resource like `/tweet` (which is a noun) and then several routes for that resource like `create`, `edit` and `delete`.

Comment: In case anyone wonders when to use `resource()` vs `route()` - general rule of thumb is to use `resource()` for nouns (in this case `admin`, `photos` and `users`) and `route()` for verbs like `new`, `edit` or adjectives like `favorites` or `starred` <- taken from [Getting into Ember.js: The Next Steps blog post](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/getting-into-ember-js-part-2/).

Comment: Great point, I remember reading that on the Ember docs. I suppose a situation like above would warrant a little deviation from that general rule of thumb because there isn't another way to nest routes, right? Correct me if I'm wrong--this is the only way I thought you could do it.

Comment: So what about routes like /admin/photos/new? I don't seem to be able to access them. Here, admin is not really a resource but more like a 'section' of the website reserved for collecting administration activities.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Check out this section on the ember.js documentation for more info: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/